# Trying to add scraped data to excel workbooks Im exporting from website

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I am trying to add some data to Excel files I am exporting from a site using Python and Selenium. I would like to add this data to a column in the Excel file and I am not sure how to go about doing it. Below is the code i have to loop through and download all the files. I am going to use Pandas and combine them all, but i need to figure out how to get this extra information added to each individual Excel file i download somehow. I was thinking about scraping the extra data with Beautiful Soup I just don't have any idea how to then add that to each file. Can someone please help me.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob 
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# SET URL
driver.get(r'http://url')

#CLICK on SET
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
SET= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_body_tabs']/div[2]/ul[1]/li[2]/a/span/span/span")))
SET.click()

#SWITCH TO IFRAME
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
frm1= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='body_pnl']/div/iframe")))

driver.switch_to.frame(frm1)

region=2

while region<38:
    #CHOOSE REGION
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
    newreg= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ctl00_areaSelector']")))
    newreg.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
    xpath="//*[@id='ctl00_areaSelector']/option[{}]".format(region)
    newreg= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,xpath )))
    newreg.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    
    #Click event admin list
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
    eventadmin= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_gridView']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a")))
    eventadmin.click()
    
    Rates=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Rates')]")
    numrates=len(Rates)
    counter=0
    
    
    while counter<numrates:
        time.sleep(2)
        Rates=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Rates')]")
        Rates[counter].click()
        
        #Export Rates
        time.sleep(3)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
        exp= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_exportToExcel']")))
        exp.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        
        #click back button
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
        back= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ctl00_link1']")))
        back.click()
        
        counter+=1
        time.sleep(3)
       
    #Back to main screen
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
    back= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ctl00_link1']")))
    back.click()
    
    region+=1
```

Comment: Why are you downloading excel files when you can scrape the data? I would recommend scraping the data, make a dataframe and then write the data to an excel file

Comment: That would not be possible because there are going to be 200+ files being combined and each one needs unique data added.